# How can I extract average temperature per day from a list of measurements?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a `.txt` file like this:

```
#day hr T 0.1 d.C.
1    1  137
1    2  124
1    3  130
1    4  128
1    5  141
1    6  127
1    7  153
1    8  137
1    9  158
1    10 166
...
2   1   136
2   2   135
2   3   135
2   4   132
and so on...
```

I wrote this code:

```
import sys

NUMBEROFDAYS = []
NUMBEROFHOURS = []
Temp = []

for line in sys.stdin:
    x = (line[0:2])
    NUMBEROFDAYS.append(x)
```

What I get is:

```
['#d', '1\t', '1\t', '1\t', '1\t', '1\t', '1\t', '1\t', '1\t', '1\t',   and it goes on...
```

However I need to extract relevant integers from the text.
How do I do that?

My final goal is to compute the average temperature for each day (the temperature is represented in the 3rd column).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing up fields and characters. You have to split your string and convert splitted strings to integers.

Then, you have to create one list per day, so it's better to use a dictionary to create several temp vectors, and print the mean of each day in the end.

(note that the 2nd column is completely unused)

```
import sys

from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda : list()) # dictionary: key=day, values=temp list

sys.stdin.readline() # get rid of the title
for line in sys.stdin:
    # for each line, split it (to remove blanks, so byebye tabs and convert to integer, create a list with that: list comprehension)
    x = [int(x) for x in line.split()]
    d[x[0]].append(x[2])   # add temperature to each day

for day,temps in sorted(d.items()):
    print("day {}, average temp {}".format(day,float(sum(temps))/len(temps)))
```

result:

```
day 1, average temp 140.1
day 2, average temp 134.5
```

Comment: Yeah thanks. But I want to get the average temperature of day, day2 etc. So i must be three different list right to zip it?

Comment: I added this to your code:

      for (x, y, b) in NUMBEROFDAYS:
 total = sum(b)

    print(total)

But i get this as error:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: @jozofe because sum should have collection parameter like `list` but in your case it is `int` and why your doing `total = sum(b)` in for loop because it will assign last element value of `b` to total.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thankyou! But that's for the whole list, i have to seperate it by the average temp of day1, the average temp of day2. How do I do that?

Comment: Ok. Now I get the real need. The question wasn't clear on that point (edited). Answer (heavily) modified, but works.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to group the data by day (first column), this seems a typical case for `itertools'groupby()`:

```
from itertools import groupby

# first check if all characters in the line are integers:
valid = [l for l in open("/path/to/file.txt").readlines() if "".join(l.split()).isdigit()]
# split valid lines into numbers
data = [[int(n) for n in line.split()] for line in valid]
# group data by day (first number of the line)
day_data = [[item, list(records)] for item, records in groupby(data, key = lambda r: r[0])]
for day in day_data:
    temps = day[1]
    print(day[0], sum([r[2] for r in temps])/float(len(temps)))
```

With your lines, this will output:

```
1 140.1
2 134.5
```

#### Explanation

- First we read the textfile as a list of lines:

  ```
  open("/path/to/file.txt").readlines()
  ```
- we check if all characters are integers, after removing all whitespaces:

  ```
   if "".join(l.split()).isdigit()
  ```
- Then we split each of the valid lines into a list of three integers:

  ```
  data = [[int(n) for n in line.split()] for line in valid]
  ```
- then we use `groupby` to group the data by day (which is the first integer of each line):

  ```
  day_data = [[item, list(records)] for item, records in groupby(data, key = lambda r: r[0])]
  ```

  This will deliver us two records, one for each day:

  ```
  1, [[1, 1, 137], [1, 2, 124], [1, 3, 130], [1, 4, 128], [1, 5, 141], [1, 6, 127], [1, 7, 153], [1, 8, 137], [1, 9, 158], [1, 10, 166]
  ```

  and:

  ```
  2, [[2, 1, 136], [2, 2, 135], [2, 3, 135], [2, 4, 132]
  ```
- Subsequently, we print the day, followed by the *average* of the *third column* for that specific day:

  ```
  for day in day_data:
      temps = day[1]
      print(day[0], sum([r[2] for r in temps])/float(len(temps)))
  ```